# React Native: view that fills the remaining area between two left and right fixed views

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I have the below layout arranged as shown in the attached image

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>

    <View style={{width:90}}></View>  //fixed left container
    <View style={{flexGrow:1}}></View>    //the center view
    <View style={{width:90}}></View>    //fixed right container

</View>
```

I have 3 horizontally aligned views. 2 fixed width view on left and right. And a center view to fill up the remaining center space.

This works fine if the content inside the center view are small but the moment it grows longer it's pushing the right side view to the right, out of the parent view.

[image]

How can I make the center container to fill the middle space but not to push the right view when it grows?

Answer (score 0):

Add **flex: 1** to the center view

Comment: `flexWrap` will not work as its pushing the content below and now all the 3 views are coming in 3 lines vertically

Comment: Okay, but I think you best give the middle part also a width property so flexWrap is constrained to that width

Comment: How can you give width to something that will vary based on screen size

Comment: You can use percentages, for example: **width: '50%'** (percentages depend on parent container)

Comment: Dude I guess you didn't understand my problem. The left and right side views are fixed width (90px + 90px) so for the center view the width should be (100% - 180). not sure how to do this in react native.

Comment: Okay, simply add **flex: 1** to the center view and it will automatically fill the available space